# nodejs pass same variable in two differents middlwares

Tags: node.js

**in my app file i have two post middlwares**

```
app.post('/check',urlencodedParser,function (req, res) {
 
  var date_entre_user=req.body.dateentry;
  var date_sortie_user=req.body.datesortie;
  var idroom=req.body.room;
  let sql=`SELECT *  FROM reservation WHERE idchambre = ${req.body.room}`;
  let query=db.query(sql,(err,result)=>{

     datesortieuser=dateFormat(date_sortie_user,"isoDaTteTime");
     dateentreuser= dateFormat(date_entre_user,"isoDateime");



app.post('/submit',urlencodedParser,function (req, res) {
.numtele,
    email: req.body.email
}

 /* let clt = {
    nom: req.body.nom,
    prenom : req.body.prenom,
    cin: req.body.cin,
    ville: req.body.ville,
    pays: req.body.pays,
    tele: req.body
let sql2 = 'INSERT INTO client SET ?'
  db.query(sql2, clt,function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("1 client inserted");
  });

  let sql3 =`SELECT idclient FROM client WHERE nom = ${req.body.nom}`;
  db.query(sql3,function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
  });
```

**but when i use the variable date_entre_user in the second middleware post i got variable undefined
how can i do it?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable you mentioned is defined only in your first `.post()` method, so it isn't in scope in the second one.

If you want to pass data from one middleware function to another, a good way is to use `req.locals`, adorning the req object with the data you're passing.  Something like this.

```
/* in one function */
if (!req.locals) req.locals = {}
req.locals.date_entre_user = quelqueChose
```

and then in the next function, you can refer to that same item.